# Json Parsing in swift 2

Tags: json, parsing, swift2, uilabel

I am working on the getting the distance and time using the google maps in swift. I am trying to parse the data.Here is the son result which I am getting…….

```
data -  {
   "destination_addresses" : [
      "C.Pallavaram, Mallika Nagar, Meenambakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India"
   ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Sholinganallur, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "18.9 km",
                  "value" : 18910
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "37 mins",
                  "value" : 2193
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I am trying to get the  elements.duration.text here is the code …….

```
  do {

            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(datas!, options: .AllowFragments)



            if let blogs: NSArray = json["rows"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                print(blogs)



                print(blogs.valueForKeyPath("elements.duration.text")!)



                   let tset = String(blogs.valueForKeyPath("elements.duration.text")!.objectAtIndex(0))

                 print(tset)

                  timeLabel.text = tset

            }

        }



        catch {

            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")

        }
```

But it is coming like the below value...

(

```
"37 mins"
```

)

But i want to display it in “timeLabel.text”.Can anyone please  tell me how to get it like “37 mins”.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use swiftyjson library for parsing json -https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if let blogs = json["rows"]["elements"] as? NSArray {

    print(blogs)
   let tset = blogs[1]["duration"]["text"] as! String

    print(tset)

   timeLabel.text = tset

}
```

Comment: Glad I could help..:)